# How to encpyt the password using Springboot?

Tags: java, spring

I have already done user register and login. But I want to encrypt the password when create a profile.

This is my current configuration

MongoDB Connection

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Student
server.port=8080
```

Model Class:
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
@Id
@Indexed
private String id;
@Indexed
private String address;
@Indexed
private String name;
@Indexed
private String email;
@Indexed
private String password;
@Indexed
private String role;
}

Repository Class:

```
public interface userReporsitory extends MongoRepository<User,String> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    List<User> findAllByRole(String role);
}
```

Service Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class userService {
    private userReporsitory userReporsitory;
    public User saveUser(User user){
        return userReporsitory.save(user);    
    }
    public User login(User user){
          User response = userReporsitory.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException("User Not Found"));
          
          if(!response.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())){
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad Credincials");
          }

          return response;
    }

    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
      return userReporsitory.findAllByRole("user");
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
    @CrossOrigin
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/v1/user")
public class userController {
   private userService userService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<User> save(@RequestBody User user){
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED;
        User response = userService.saveUser(user);

        if(response != null){
           status = HttpStatus.CREATED;
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, status);
        
    }
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(@RequestBody User user){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.login(user),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        
    }
    @GetMapping("/userList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> userList(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.findAllUsers(),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
        

}
```

Comment: I think you should consider using spring-security to utilize its `PasswordEncoder` and different ways to compare passwords for equality

Comment: the best practice is to hash passwords not encrypt them, as @AndrewThomas use any implementation of PasswordEncoder like BCryptPasswordEncoder

Answer (score 1):

Use

> **BCryptPasswordEncoder**

Class while saving the Password in DataBase.it will convert the normal text to RandomValue.

Define the BCryptPasswordEncoder In config Class.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Repository Class :

```
   @Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public User newUserAccount(UserDto accountDto) {
        User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(accountDto.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(accountDto.getLastName());
   
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));
    
    
    return repository.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize this code .. Here I am using InMemoryUserDetailsManager to manage user details that stored in memory.

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager createUserDetails(){
    UserDetails user1 = createNewUser("vamsi","vamsi");
    UserDetails user2 = createNewUser("a","a");

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1,user2);

}

private UserDetails createNewUser(String username, String password) {
    Function<String, String> passwordEncoder = input ->passwordEncoder().encode(input);
    return User.builder()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .password(password)
            .username(username)
            .roles("user","admin")
            .build();
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```